# Summing values in Spark RDD where assigned clusters are equal

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, k-means, rdd

I have a PySpark program that takes descriptions of variables and uses the Spark Word2Vec model to transform the descriptions into vectors, then uses KMeans to cluster those vectors in order to group descriptions that are hopefully describing the same thing.

However, the dataset has many duplicates in it.  I deduplicate the original dataset, but maintain a count with each unique row of how many duplicates of that description existed originally.

After clustering the descriptions vectors, I zip the result rdd back into the dataset with descriptions. I would like to order the clusters based on how many total entries of data mapped to that cluster.  So, the final RDD looks like this:

```
[([companyid=u'xxxxxxxx', variableid=u'prop11', description=u'payment method',duplicateCount=u'8', word2vecOutput=DenseVector([.830574, 1.96709, -0.86785,......])], clusterID=793]
```

The cluster is separated because it was zipped back into the W2V rdd. 
I want to find a way to aggregate all the duplicateCount values and make an ordered list that has a clusterID with it's total number of original rows (before deduplication) ordered by total original rows.

It seems like this should be really easy to do with a simple aggregate function, but for whatever reason, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Thanks for any help

EDIT:

To clarify, in each row of my RDD, there is a number labeled duplicateCount.  There is another element labeled cluster.  I was trying to write a function that would sum the duplicateCount where the cluster is equal, thereby giving me a totalCount for each cluster.

For example, 4 elements might be grouped into cluster 10.  However, the first element might have a duplicateCount of 5, the second a duplicateCount of 37, etc (still all in cluster 10).  I want to sum the duplicates in every cluster so I can get an actual size of the cluster.

I thought the W2V and KMeans would provide helpful context about why I wanted it, but apparently it just made the question confusing

Comment: What is the question ? Please review your description, what you are asking isn't clear !

Comment: *By the way, **K-means** doesn't work with **categorical features**.* You can read this post [K-means clustering for mixed numeric and categorical data](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data) to notice the reasons.

Comment: I edited the original post to clarify. I'm clustering the vectors that come as output to word2vec (which is a vector of 100 numbers), not the words themselves.  

Also, what is unclear about the post? I essentially have a dataframe with, among other things, a cluster ID and a duplicate count.  I want to add together all duplicate count numbers where the cluster IDs are equal, so that I can get a total count for each cluster